# Does the direction of coil winding impact the direction of induced voltage?

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, physics, magnetic-flux, faradays-law

I have taken and modified a bit the following image from a similar question, where it was explained that the direction of the coil winding does not impact the direction of the current: [Does coil winding impact current direction? (Lenz Law)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613579/does-coil-winding-impact-current-direction-lenz-law)

However I'm not so sure about the direction of the induced voltage. Can you please explain to me that in Case 1) and Case 2) which end of the coil will be more positive, A or B?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, the arrow (when used to indicate current direction) points *from* more positive *to* more negative as current direction is considered to be direction of motion of positive charges.

Comment: If that's not clear, wire it up [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dxVj.png).

Comment: @jonk No, this is not how I meant it. My question is what will be the direction of the induced voltage in Case 1) and Case 2). It is one image, but they are two separate cases.

Comment: Clockwise vs anticlockwise matters; left-right or right-left doesn't (from the magnetic field POV)

Comment: @user_1818839 Yes, the current will flow in both cases counterclockwise (from the magnet's POV). But now imagine you connect a resistor between point A and B (so parallel with the coil). In Case 1) the current will flow on it from A to B so induced voltage drops from A to B. However in Case 2) current will flow on it from B to A so induced voltage drops from B to A. But this seems strange to me that the direction of the coil winding would affect the direction of the induced voltage. I think I get mistaken somewhere along my explanation. I hope you see my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone, who is interested in the answer, I opened a question about it at physics.stackexchange.com. You can find the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/712905/does-the-direction-of-coil-winding-impact-the-direction-of-induced-voltage).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine looking in from the left (N) end of the coil.

From that perspective, the winding current appears be clockwise, although with a slight 'drift' either towards or away from the viewer. With the right-hand rule (hand grasping one of the wires), you can see that the direction of magnetic flux is also the same in either case.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the direction of the magnetic flux will be the same in both cases. But now imagine you connect a resistor between point A and B (so parallel with the coil). In Case 1) the current will flow on it from A to B so induced voltage drops from A to B. However in Case 2) current will flow on it from B to A so induced voltage drops from B to A. But this seems strange to me that the direction of the coil winding would affect the direction of the induced voltage. I think I get mistaken somewhere along my explanation. I hope you see my problem.

Comment: Visualize like this: The induced voltage (technically an e.m.f.) is induced in each loop. Those loops are stacked in series, and the resistor is connected to the ends of the system. The low voltage end is the one where the current flows out of the coil. This is different in your case 1 and case 2 drawings. If you exchanged 'A' and 'B' in case 2, you'd find the current still flows (externally) from A to B

Comment: If I exchanged point A and point B in Case 2), then I would get exactly Case 1) back. But still, my question is there, in which direction does the voltage drop in the two cases?

Comment: What I mean is change the labels; leave the wires identical.

Comment: So you just simply want to delete my Case 2), and only deal with Case 1)? :-)